# Grunt won't install on my project

Tags: npm, gruntjs, npm-install

I've been trying to install grunt on my project but no luck.

Here's the error i get when running npm install

```
npm WARN package.json XXX@1.0.0 No license field.
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v0.12.7
npm ERR! npm  v2.11.3
npm ERR! code EPEERINVALID

npm ERR! peerinvalid The package grunt does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-contrib-copy@0.8.2 wants grunt@>=0.4.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-contrib-sass@0.9.2 wants grunt@>=0.4.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-contrib-watch@0.6.1 wants grunt@~0.4.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-mustache-render@1.9.0 wants grunt@^0.4.5
```

Heres' what my package json looks like

```
{
  "name": "XXX",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "some git repo"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt-html-build": "^0.5.1",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "^0.8.0",
    "grunt-contrib-sass": "^0.9.2",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "^0.6.1",
    "grunt-mustache-render": "^1.9.0"
  }
}
```

I've tried npm update -g but nothing much seems to happen.

npm --version says 2.11.3

the only relevant error i think i found was when i ran

```
> npm list
├─┬ grunt@1.0.1 peer invalid
```

and at the end: npm ERR! peer invalid: grunt@1.0.1

```
> grunt --version
grunt-cli v1.2.0
grunt v1.0.1
```

do i need to re-install grunt or something ? I haven't found a command for that.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 6):

Some grunt-plugins haven't updated their peer dependency requirements yet to work with the 1.0 version of grunt (1.0 is fairly new).  You can try to remove the peer dependency requirements, but that could be problematic depending on what changes were made between 0.4.5 and 1.0. (0.4.5 was the last version prior to 1.0)

Try installing the version of grunt that's compatible with the plugins first: `npm install grunt@^0.4.5 --save-dev`

Answer (score 0):

For npm version 2, you should have grunt version 0.4.5

**"devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "^0.4.5" }**

As you seen below , npm version is less than 3 so you should have **grunt version: ^0.4.5**
$ **npm --version
2.15.11**

Answer (score -1):

Output from npm install explains everything pretty good:

```
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-contrib-copy@0.8.2 wants grunt@>=0.4.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-contrib-sass@0.9.2 wants grunt@>=0.4.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-contrib-watch@0.6.1 wants grunt@~0.4.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-mustache-render@1.9.0 wants grunt@^0.4.5
```

To understand it you need to understand semantical versioning explained here:

https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#version

and here

https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/semver

In order to fix the problem you must specify more flexible version number for packages that block installation of new grunt.

Just set ">= 0.0.0" requirement for all grunt plugins and their versions will be synchronized with grunt version by npm.

```
 "devDependencies": {
    "grunt-html-build": ">=0.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": ">=0.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-sass": ">=0.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": ">=0.0.0",
    "grunt-mustache-render": ">=0.0.0"
  }
```

Comment: Thx. I don't see how it explains pretty good when the error clearly says that it needs grunt > 0.4.0, and i have grunt 1.0.1 ?

Comment: >=0.4.0 mets version of your grunt while ~0.4.0 and ^0.4.0 does not. Here is the tricky part. You can specify grunt version that meets all requirements like `npm install --save grunt@0.4.0`

Comment: i tried to change the package.json like you said and replaced everything with >=0.0.0 same error. Same errors if i try npm install --save grunt@0.4.0